# Spring Integration is hitting mutliple outbound requests even the request is failing

Tags: spring-integration-dsl

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow initiateFlowGeocode3() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory());
    System.out.println("**********in flow3");
    return IntegrationFlows.from("FlowChannel2").transform(Transformers.toJson()).log("IN  GATEWAY 3 !").handle(
            Http.outboundGateway("URL",
                    restTemplate).charset("UTF-8").httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET).expectedResponseType(String.class)
                   .errorHandler(new MyResponseErrorHandler()))
            .log("after the rest api call3 ").transform(new JsonToObjectTransformer(RestClientBean.class)).get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorResponse() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(renewalErrorChannel()).log("ERROR FLOW TRIGGERED").get();
}

@Bean
public PollableChannel renewalErrorChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}
```

is continuously getting hit. If there's a failure, the flow should stop hitting it, but it's continuously polling the failure request. Can the polling request be stopped?